# Eureka Server : Getting 503 service unavailable when accessing a endpoint URL

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I have created an API gateway, a microservice ( coursehandler ), and a Eureka server.

when try to access the end point from Postman I get 503.

What I am doing wrong?

### postman

http://localhost:8090/course/getallcourses

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-04-04T11:54:19.850+00:00",
    "path": "/course/getallcourses",
    "status": 503,
    "error": "Service Unavailable",
    "requestId": "3281f2e6-1"
}
```

## Application.yml for course application

```
server:
  port: 8083

spring:
  application:
    name: CourseHandlerApplication
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
    username: springuser
    password: password
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  
      
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8091/eureka
```

## Application.yml for API gateway

```
server:
  port: 8090
 
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: CourseHandlerApplication
        uri: lb://CourseHandlerApplication/
        predicates:
        - Path=/course/*
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8091/eureka
```

## Application.yml for Eureka server

```
spring:
  application:
    name: service-discovery
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8091/eureka
logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    '[org.springframework.cloud]': TRACE
    '[org.springframework.cloud.gateway.RouteDefinitionLocator]': INFO    
   
server:
  port: 8091
```

Trying to register a microservice and access via Eureka